# databaseReference.observe(DataEventType.value, with:{(DataSnapshot) not working properly all the time

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
func checkPaid(utilityId : String) -> Int{

        var amount:String = ""
        var status = 0
        print("inside new function ")
        print ("\(utilityId) inside new function ")
        self.databaseRefPayment.observe(DataEventType.value, with:{(DataSnapshot) in
          if  DataSnapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
            for payments in DataSnapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
                  var paymentsObject = payments.value as? NSDictionary

                    /*
                    if(paymentsObject!["month"] as! String == monthCheck && paymentsObject!["year"] as! String == monthCheck && paymentsObject!["utilityid"] as! String == utilityId as! String){ */
                    if(paymentsObject!["utilityId"] as! String == utilityId){

                        amount = paymentsObject!["amount"] as! String
                        print(amount)
                        print("Ypur program is working perfect")
                        status = 1

                    }
                }
            }
        })

        return status
  }
```

The above function is filtering the data present in payments node based on the value for `utilityId` getting passed in the function . But the strange thing is `observe(DataEventType.value, with:{(DataSnapshot)` this event is not getting triggered all the time . Its just skipping that portion unnecessarily . I am very new to firebase and getting really mad with these kind of unpredicted behaviours . Please help me in this . feel free to ask for any clarifications .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firebase executes firebase query functions in different thread , so after u call check paid(), it runs the checkpaid() firebase query in another thread,and it will return from the function , eventhough ur query is running in the background..so it will seem like,checkpaid() is not working , but actually it's running on another thread.

I think you first fetch all the required data from payment, and store it in a list , and then use that list to compare with utility.

Comment: Thanks much Jerin . I did it like the way you mentioned and it worked . :-) That was really a new knowledge for me . Thanks once again .

Answer (score 0):

Every time this function is called it adds/resets the Key-Value Observer for whichever child node you are observing *it doesn't actually check the value unless it is changed*. I believe it is your intention to call checkPaid(utilityId:) to check the child is 'paid' by some means. There is no need to add a KVO if you are directly reading the value for a single snapshot. consider the following:

```
func checkPaid(utilityId: String) -> Bool {
    //Assume it is not paid if we cannot verify it.
    var isPaid = false
    //Create a new reference to Firebase Database
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    ref = Database.database().reference().child(utilityId)

    //Get the values for the child, test if it is paid or not.
    ref.queryOrderedByValue().observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if (snapshot.value is NSNull) {
            print("No Child With \(utilityId) Exists")
        } else  {
            //child with utilityId exists, in case multiple utilityId's exist with the same value..
            for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                if let values = child.value as? [String : AnyObject] {

                    let uid = child.key //utilityId

                    var month:String = ""
                    var year:String = ""
                    var amount:String = ""
                    //var amount:Double = 0.0

                    //get values from parent
                    if let m = values["month"] as? String {
                        month = m
                    }

                    if let y = values["year"] as? String {
                        year = y
                    }

                    if let a = values["amount"] as? String {
                        amount = a
                    }

                    /*
                     if let a = values["amount"] as? Double {
                        amount = a
                     }
                     */



                    //??
                    if ((month == monthCheck) && (year == monthCheck)) {
                        isPaid = true
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    return isPaid
}
```

I am making one assumption here; that utilityId is the key for the child.
if you have parent nodes to utilityId you'll have to transverse those as well when you reference the database:

```
ref = Database.database().reference().child(utilities).child(utilityId) ..etc
```

If you need a KVO to update a local property I suggest adding/calling it in viewDidLoad, it's completion handler should take care of updating whichever properties are updated when they change in Firebase.

Comment: Hi Ercell,Thank you co much for taking time to analyze and answer my question.But one clarification I need to give is utilityId is not a key in the Payments table as the same utility can have many payments for different dates.Payments has its own key and under that the key value pairs for utilityId,month,year,amount will come . I tried the solution you have provided but as you assume utilityId as the key it will not work here . I was trying to fix the issue by myself but still its not going inside the block starting with "ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in " .

Comment: Still I am confused why DataEventType.value is not returning all the values in Payments node .why is it simply exiting from it even though Payments has got valid data in it. Once again thanks a lot for your prompt response . Sorry for my silly doubts like I said before I am very new to this kind of database .

Comment: can someone help me in this ?I even tried this code for my listener        ref.queryEqual(toValue: utilityId, childKey: "utilityId").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in    after going though the answer provided by Ercell. But still that block is getting skipped